# Query Notifications vs SQL Server Notifications Services

Tags: sql-server, notifications, sql-server-2012

Is there a correlation between SQL Server Notifications Services which was discontinued in SQL 2005 and Query Notifications? Was Query Notifications meant to replace SQL Server Notifications Services or are they two totally different technologies?

I have googled around but couldn't find any clear answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Absolutely nothing in common, other than the fact that both contain 'Notifications' int he name. The replacement technology for Notification Services is [Reporting Services (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx) (I know the overlap is far from perfect).

Comment: Wow I didn't expect that at all! I wonder what prompted them to make that decision. To me they seem to cater to two different needs.